# Using FOR XML to group against 2 sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a sql query below, that I would like to format as XML using the FOR XML syntax.

```
SELECT
  gr.id,
  gr.created,
  ts.ordernumber
FROM trGrouped gr
INNER JOIN transactions ts
  ON ts.grouped_id = gr.id
WHERE ts.ordernumber IN ('4003970100000383', '4003970100000376', '4003970100000369', '1022108100000018')
```

This is an example of the XML format I would like the query to look like.

```
<trans_groups>
  <grouped id="56" created="4/14/2017">
    <ordernumber>1022108100000001</ordernumber>
    <ordernumber>1022108100000002</ordernumber>
    <ordernumber>1022108100000003</ordernumber>
  </grouped>
  <grouped id="57" created="4/14/2017">
    <ordernumber>1022109100000001</ordernumber>
    <ordernumber>1022109100000002</ordernumber>
  </grouped>
</trans_groups>
```

So far I have not been able to get this quite right. I have tried the following but this is not grouping the orders.

```
select gr.id as [@id], gr.created as [@created],
    (
    SELECT ts.ordernumber as ordernumber
    )
FROM trGrouped gr inner join transactions ts on ts.grouped_id = gr.id
    where ts.ordernumber in('4003970100000383', '4003970100000376', '4003970100000369', '1022108100000018')
FOR XML PATH('grouped'), ROOT('trans_groups')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,created date, ordernumber varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (56,'04/14/2017','1022108100000001')
,(56,'04/14/2017','1022108100000002')
,(56,'04/14/2017','1022108100000003')
,(57,'04/14/2017','1022109100000001')
,(57,'04/14/2017','1022109100000002')

Select [@id]      = id
      ,[@created] = convert(VARCHAR(10), created, 101)
      ,(
        Select ordernumber
         From  @YourTable A1
         Where A1.id = A.id
         For XML Path(''), type
       )
 From  (Select Distinct ID,Created From @YourTable ) A
 For XML Path('grouped'), Root('trans_groups')
```

**Returns**

```
<trans_groups>
  <grouped id="56" created="04/14/2017">
    <ordernumber>1022108100000001</ordernumber>
    <ordernumber>1022108100000002</ordernumber>
    <ordernumber>1022108100000003</ordernumber>
  </grouped>
  <grouped id="57" created="04/14/2017">
    <ordernumber>1022109100000001</ordernumber>
    <ordernumber>1022109100000002</ordernumber>
  </grouped>
</trans_groups>
```

Comment: Very nice! In general, is there a difference between the `select distinct` derived table vs. `group by id, created`? http://rextester.com/ZLS77092

Comment: @SqlZim On larger data sets, I've found DISTINCT to be faster, not much, but noticable.  This may have been tribal knowledge so I will revisit, and run some benchmarks in a bit.

Comment: @SqlZim With a sample size of 80,000 records,  the average runtime of the DISTINCT was 327ms while the GROUP BY was 412MS

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
select gr.id as [@id], gr.created as [@created],
    (
    SELECT ordernumber as ordernumber from transactions where grouped_id = grouped_id
    and ordernumber in ('4003970100000383', '4003970100000376', '4003970100000369', '1022108100000018')
    FOR XML path(''), type
    )
FROM (SELECT distinct gr.id, created FROM trGrouped gr inner join transactions ts on ts.grouped_id = gr.id
    where ts.ordernumber in('4003970100000383', '4003970100000376', '4003970100000369', '1022108100000018')) gr 
FOR XML PATH('grouped'), ROOT('trans_groups')
```